# Postgres Array[VarChar] uppercase?

Tags: sql, postgresql, jdbc

I'm trying to find a way to force an array to make it upper or lowercase. This is so that no matter what the user inputs they get a result. This is the query:

```
select * from table where any(:id) = databasecolumn
```

:id is an array of chars that the user inputs(can be lowercase or uppercase) and I need to make sure that whatever the user inputs they get a result.

This works as long as the user inputs in uppercase (because the database values are also uppercase). But when they input lowercase letters they get no response.

I tried this:

```
select * from table where any(upper(:id)) = upper(databasecolumn)
```

but this does not work because the function "upper" is not for arrays. It works fine when I do it with a single input but not arrays.

Do you have any pointers? I couldn't find an equivalent function for an array of varchars.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  By default, isn't the comparison already case-insensitive?  Why do you need to apply `upper` at all?

Answer (score 4):

You could use `ILIKE`:

```
select * 
from table 
where databasecolumn ILIKE any(:id);
```

This:

```
with data (col) as (
  values ('one'), ('Two'), ('THREE')
)
select *
from data
where col ilike any(array['one', 'two', 'three']);
```

returns:

```
col  
-----
one  
Two  
THREE
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use double casting like here:

```
t=# with a as (select '{caSe1,cAse2}'::text[] r) select r,upper(r::text)::text[] from a where true;
       r       |     upper
---------------+---------------
 {caSe1,cAse2} | {CASE1,CASE2}
(1 row)
```

It neglects the benefits of using `ANY` though