# In Postgres how do I apply UPPER/LOWER on a list of strings? I am able to apply UPPER/LOWER on a single String

Tags: postgresql

However when I tried on a list of String it is throwing error.

```
select distinct(tx.sub_tran_type)  
from tran.txn tx
where tx.sub_tran_type = UPPER('homede')
limit 100
```

This query runs fine . However if you look at

```
select distinct(tx.sub_tran_type)  
from tran.txn tx
where tx.sub_tran_type  in UPPER('homede','online','omni-online','amznow')            
limit 100
```

It throws this error:

> SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "UPPER"`

Comment: You have to use upper() on each single value, inside the IN() comparison

Comment: Change it to upper(tx.sub_tran_type)  in ('HOMEDE','ONLINE','OMNI-ONLINE','AMZNOW').

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: `distinct` is **not** a function. It always applies to all columns in the select list. Enclosing one of the columns after DISTINCT with parentheses won't change anything and is useless. `distinct (a),b` is the same as `distinct a,(b)` or `distinct a,b`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Postgres Array\[VarChar\] uppercase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42927443/postgres-arrayvarchar-uppercase)

Answer (score 1):

This is just a trick. You can try this with your case:

```
select distinct tx.sub_tran_type
from tran.txn tx
where tx.sub_tran_type in (SELECT upper(unnest(array['homede','online','omni-online','amznow'])))
limit 100
```